# How can I get intellisense for css classes to work in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: asp.net-core, tailwind-css, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to integrate tailwindcss into an asp.net core mvc project in visual studio 2022. I searched the internet and came up with the suggestion to add the following snippet of XML to the project file. I had to modify the path because apparently the folder structure within the tailwindcss folder within node_modules has changed.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\css\*.css" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I am still not getting any intellisense support for tailwindscss classes.